# The slice of type 'Discovery' is 'Aborted' because of the error : System.Exception: NUnit Adapter 4.0.0.0: Test discovery complete

Tags: azure-devops, nunit

I tried to run Azure DevOps tests in a build pipeline.
Tests are executed on a new agent, i got the following error.

[Setup Azure DevOps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSVQC.png)

##[error]The slice of type 'Discovery' is 'Aborted' because of the error : System.Exception: NUnit Adapter 4.0.0.0: Test discovery complete
Received the command : Stop
TestExecutionHost.ProcessCommand. Stop Command handled
SliceFetch Aborted. Moving to the TestHostEnd phase
Test run '1007278' is in 'Aborted' state.
##[error]Test run is aborted. Logging details of the run logs.
##[error]System.Exception: The test run was aborted, failing the task.

Comment: Hi Lukas, what's the result if you place the VS Test task in the same agent job where the assembly was built? We can check whether this is environment-related issue first.

Comment: Hi, before i moved the task the VS Task was running on the same agent and everything worked fine, so it seems to be a issue with the setup ?!

Comment: Yes, I believe this issue is related to environment. Possible cause: 1. You installed .net core 3 in first agent, but you didn't install .net core in second agent. 2.You restore/build the test project in first agent, so you have assemblies related to test framework in first agent, but these assemblies are missing in second agent.

Comment: Now i added the task for .net core 3 to the second agent too and a nuget restore, but still the same issue.
I tried the same setup with Execution plan "None", everything work fine, but if i change to multi-agent and set value to 2, the error is shown.

Comment: Are you using self-hosted agent or hosted agent? Do you have parallel jobs?

Comment: I use hosted agent and this is the first job where i want to use the parallel execution.

Comment: Could it be that there is a problem with VSTest Job with Nunit and parallel execution ?
If i set number of agent to "one" everything work fine, so it seems that the slice of the tests do not work correctly, i read about this issue in other blogs, can anyone confirm that this is a know problem ?

Comment: Found solution/reason: The Problem is that after slice process the test case filter isn't working, solution was the rename to “TestCategory”, before it was “Category“ for TestCaseFilter

Comment: Got it and glad to know it works. You can consider adding it as self answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is that after slice process the test case filter isn't working, solution was the rename to “TestCategory”, before it was “Category“ for TestCaseFilter